How to simplify $\left( \frac{26}{27} - \frac{5}{3\sqrt{3}} \right)^{1/3}+\left( \frac{26}{27} + \frac{5}{3\sqrt{3}} \right)^{1/3} $?
I am trying to help my 17-year-old son understand how to simplify the expression
$$
\left( \frac{26}{27} - \frac{5}{3\sqrt{3}} \right)^{1/3}+\left( \frac{26}{27} + \frac{5}{3\sqrt{3}} \right)^{1/3}
$$
to
$$
\frac43
$$
without knowing the simplified form in advance.
What systematic approach or techniques can be used to demonstrate this equality? Any insights on algebraic manipulations or recognizing patterns in cube roots would be greatly appreciated.
Martin Liebeck in his Introduction to Pure Mathematics (p.52) treats a similar expression
but unfortunately he does not provide any insight about the simplification.

PS I know there are similar questions in MSE but I am looking for something as simple as possible. Thanks a lot.

Please check this post and the posts linked on it.

Welcome to Math SE. Note that, similar to what's done in this answer to the question that Soheil's comment above links to, if $c=a+b$, then $c^3=(a+b)^3=a^3+3ab(a+b)+b^3=a^3+3abc+b^3$. Also, $a^3$, $ab$ and $b^3$ are quite simple resulting values in your particular case.

With a little manipulation, we can see the problem reduces to $\frac{1}{3}( (26 - 15\sqrt{3})^{1/3} + (26 + 15\sqrt{3})^{1/3})$ and we can also observe that $(2 \pm \sqrt{3})^3 = 26 \pm 15\sqrt{3}$

You have to set up a cubic equation and try to find a rarional root.
The numbers inside thw cube root have the form $r\pm s\sqrt3$ with $r$ and $s$ positive and rational, so assume
$\sqrt[3]{\frac{26}{27}+\frac59\sqrt3}=x+y\sqrt3\tag{1}$
and the conjugate
$\sqrt[3]{\frac{26}{27}-\frac59\sqrt3}=x-y\sqrt3\tag{2}$
with $x$ and $y$ intended to be positive and rational. (If not you don't have a simple denesting.)
Multiplying these assumed forms (1,2) gives
$\sqrt[3]{\frac{676}{729}-\frac{675}{729}}=x^2-3y^2,$
where the left side is just $\sqrt[3]{\frac1{729}}=\frac19$.  So
$x^2-3y^2=\frac19\implies x^2=3y^2+\frac19\tag{3}$
Now, take the cube of (1) to get
$\frac{26}{27}+\frac59\sqrt3=(x+y\sqrt3)^3=(x^3+9xy^2)+(3x^2y+3y^3)\sqrt3,\tag{4}$
where we used the binomial expansion to cube the right side and then collected terms with $\sqrt3$ and terms without that radical.
Then equating the $\sqrt3$ terms in (4) and using (3) to eliminate $x$ we have
$9y^3+\frac13y+y^3=\frac59\implies 108y^3+3y-5=0.$
We now seek a positive rational root, which must be a factor of $5$ divided by a factor of $108$ according to the rational root theorem. Skipping the quadratic term actually means the square of the denominator must divide evenly into $108$, so the denominator in the proposed rational root must be $\in\{1,2,3,6\}$. Use this to cut down on trials and eventually render
$y=\frac13$
as a root.
So from (3)
$x^2=3(\frac13)^2+\frac19=\frac49 \implies x=\frac23,$
and we finally have
$\sqrt[3]{\frac{26}{27}\pm\frac59\sqrt3}=\frac23\pm\frac13\sqrt3.$
Adding up the two simplified radical expressions, with opposite $\pm$ signs, then gives the claimed answer $\frac43$.

HINT
Call the proposed expression $x$ and apply the identity:
\begin{align*}
x^{3} = (a + b)^{3} = a^{3} + b^{3} + 3ab(a + b)
\end{align*}
where the values of $a$ and $b$ are given, respectively, by
\begin{align*}
a := \left(\frac{26}{27} - \frac{5}{3\sqrt{3}}\right)^{1/3}\quad\text{and}\quad b:= \left(\frac{26}{27} + \frac{5}{3\sqrt{3}}\right)^{1/3}
\end{align*}
In order to proceed from then, notice that
\begin{align*}
(ab)^{3} = \left(\frac{26}{27} - \frac{5}{3\sqrt{3}}\right)\left(\frac{26}{27} + \frac{5}{3\sqrt{3}}\right) & = \left(\frac{26}{27}\right)^{2} - \left(\frac{5}{3\sqrt{3}}\right)^{2} = \frac{1}{27}\left(\frac{26^{2}}{27} - 25\right) = \frac{1}{27^{2}}
\end{align*}
which results into a cubic equation which has just one real root. More precisely, here it is:
\begin{align*}
x^{3} = \frac{52}{27} + \frac{x}{3} & \Longleftrightarrow 27x^{3} - 9x - 52 = 0
\end{align*}

$a^3=...$ and $b^3=...$ in your middle two equations, maybe?

Thanks for the comment. I forgot to put the appropriate exponents.
